# Malloc use in C to correctly allocate 2D array

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, segmentation-fault, malloc

A simple program must save in a 2D array:

first row -> ('k','f') 
second row -> ('c','d')

The program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char **p;

    p = (char**) malloc (2*sizeof(char*));
    *p = (char*) malloc (2*sizeof(char));

    **p = 'k';
    **(p+1) = 'f';
    *p = *p+1;
    **p = 'c';
    **(p+1) = 'd';
}
```

The program returns an error of segmentation core fault.
What is wrong?

Comment: What on earth are all those shenanigans with the pointers supposed to accomplish?

Comment: There are a *million* of examples on how to allocate a *jagged* "2D" array all over the Internet. Have you tried to search for it first?

Comment: Read also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186620/discussion-on-question-by-lorenzo-appino-malloc-use-in-c-to-correctly-allocate-2).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm deleting your most recent comments. As explained above, comments are not for extended discussion, and this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186620/discussion-on-question-by-lorenzo-appino-malloc-use-in-c-to-correctly-allocate-2). If you have anything to say about this post that is pertinent to the question (not just arguing about what the standard says or means), please feel free to comment or post in the chat. Please do not post more comments about the standard.

Comment: The "2D array" phrase is irrelevant. The question shows no arrays at all (but pointers, which are *not* arrays), and 2D arrays might not exist in C (at least, that is debatable). So please remove the "array" word and explain what a 2D non-array (perhaps pointer) could be. Pointers and arrays are not the same (even if there is some relation between them).

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch remove your want to be perfectly mathematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem at the line

> `**(p+1) = 'f';`

where you want to write into the address memorized in `*(p+1)` (e.g. `p[1]`), but you never initialized `p[1]`, and you write into an invalid address

---

It is very easy to find that kind of problem using *valgrind*, if I execute you program that gives :

```
==3951== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3951== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3951== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3951== Command: ./a.out
==3951== 
==3951== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==3951==    at 0x10494: main (c.c:11)
==3951== 
==3951== Invalid write of size 1
==3951==    at 0x10494: main (c.c:11)
==3951==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3951== 
==3951== 
==3951== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3951==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==3951==    at 0x10494: main (c.c:11)
==3951==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3951==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3951==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3951==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3951==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3951== 
==3951== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3951==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 2 blocks
==3951==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 10 bytes allocated
==3951== 
==3951== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3951==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3951==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3951==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3951==    still reachable: 10 bytes in 2 blocks
==3951==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3951== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3951== 
==3951== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3951== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3951== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

where you see both the access to the non initialized value and its use

Comment: Thank you so much Bruno.